# Cannot position controls in Toolbar and OverflowToolbar

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to add 2 Input controls to my Toolbar with Title. But in OverflowToolbar they go to overflow area and in Toolbar control are not moved to the right side by ToolbarSpacer. How do I make this work as expected?

```
    <Table
            id="sfcTable"
            mode="MultiSelect"
            items="{path: 'sfcTable>/Rowsets/Rowset/0/Row', sorter: { path: 'Shop Order'}}">
            <headerToolbar>
                    <OverflowToolbar>
                                    <Title
                                            text="Table Header Here"
                                            level="H1" />
                                    <ToolbarSpacer />
                                    <Input
                                            id="operationDelay"
                                            maxLength="6"
                                            type="Number"
                                            description="ms"
                                            fieldWidth="5rem">
                                            <layoutData>
                                                    <OverflowToolbarLayoutData
                                                            priority="NeverOverflow" />
                                            </layoutData>
                                    </Input>
                                    <Input
                                            id="actionDelay"
                                            maxLength="6"
                                            type="Number"
                                            description="ms"
                                            fieldWidth="5rem">
                                            <layoutData>
                                                    <OverflowToolbarLayoutData
                                                            priority="NeverOverflow" />
                                            </layoutData>
                                    </Input>
                    </OverflowToolbar>
            </headerToolbar>
    ...
    </Table>
```

[OverflowToolbar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXqYx.jpg)

Note that only one Input is shown.

Toolbar code:

```
    <Table
            id="sfcTable"
            mode="MultiSelect"
            items="{path: 'sfcTable>/Rowsets/Rowset/0/Row', sorter: { path: 'Shop Order'}}">
            <headerToolbar>
                    <Toolbar>
                                    <Title
                                            text="Table Header Here"
                                            level="H1" />
                                    <ToolbarSpacer />
                                    <Input
                                            id="operationDelay"
                                            maxLength="6"
                                            type="Number"
                                            description="ms"
                                            fieldWidth="5rem">
                                    </Input>
                                    <Input
                                            id="actionDelay"
                                            maxLength="6"
                                            type="Number"
                                            description="ms"
                                            fieldWidth="5rem">
                                    </Input>
                    </Toolbar>
            </headerToolbar>
```

[Toolbar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlM4K.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem at some point and ended up with wrapping the additional controls into a nested Toolbar. See working example in snippet below or at JSBin: http://jsbin.com/hofuvum/edit?html,output

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
 <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge' />
 <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8'/>
 
 <title>JSFragment used in XmlView</title>
 
 <!-- Load UI5, select Blue Crystal theme and the "commons" control library -->
 <script id='sap-ui-bootstrap' type='text/javascript'
  src='https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js'
   data-sap-ui-theme='sap_bluecrystal'
   data-sap-ui-libs='sap.m, sap.ui.commons'></script>
 
 
 <!-- DEFINE RE-USE COMPONENTS - NORMALLY DONE IN SEPARATE FILES -->
 
  
 <!-- define an XMLView - normally done in a separate file -->
 <script id="view1" type="sapui5/xmlview">
  <mvc:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:layout="sap.ui.commons.layout" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m"
    controllerName="my.own.controller" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                    <OverflowToolbar>
                                    <Title
                                            text="Table Header Here"
                                            level="H1" />
                                    <ToolbarSpacer />
                            <Toolbar>
                                    <Input
                                            id="operationDelay"
                                            maxLength="6"
                                            type="Number"
                                            description="ms"
                                            fieldWidth="5rem">
                                    </Input>
                                    <Input
                                            id="actionDelay"
                                            maxLength="6"
                                            type="Number"
                                            description="ms"
                                            fieldWidth="5rem">
                                    </Input>
                          </Toolbar>
                    </OverflowToolbar>
      </mvc:View> 
 </script>
 
 
 <script>
  // define a new (simple) Controller type
  sap.ui.controller("my.own.controller", {
   
  });
  /*** THIS IS THE "APPLICATION" CODE ***/
  
  // instantiate the View
  var myView = sap.ui.xmlview("myView", {viewContent:jQuery('#view1').html()}); // accessing the HTML inside the script tag above
      
  // put the View onto the screen
  myView.placeAt('content');
  
  
 </script>
 
 </head>
 <body class='sapUiBody'>
  <div id='content'></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you apply fieldWidth...
Here is working example based on your code: https://jsbin.com/pivodos/edit?html,output

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>SAPUI5 single file template | nabisoft</title>
        <script
            src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
            data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
            data-sap-ui-preload="async"></script>
 
        <!-- XMLView -->
        <script id="myXmlView" type="ui5/xmlview">
            <mvc:View
                xmlns="sap.m"
                xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
                xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
 
                <Table>                
                    <headerToolbar>                    
                        <OverflowToolbar>
                        
                            <Title text="Table with OverflowToolbar" level="H1" />
                            
                            <ToolbarSpacer />
                            
                            <Input
                                maxLength="6"
                                type="Number"
                                description="ms"
                                width="10rem"
                                fieldWidth="50%">
                                <layoutData>
                                    <OverflowToolbarLayoutData priority="NeverOverflow" />
                                </layoutData>
                            </Input>
                            
                            <Input
                                maxLength="6"
                                type="Number"
                                description="ms"
                                width="10rem"
                                fieldWidth="50%">
                                <layoutData>
                                    <OverflowToolbarLayoutData priority="NeverOverflow" />
                                </layoutData>
                            </Input>
                            
                        </OverflowToolbar>                        
                    </headerToolbar>                    
                </Table>
                
                <Table>                
                    <headerToolbar>                    
                        <Toolbar>
                        
                            <Title text="Table with Toolbar" level="H1" />
                            
                            <ToolbarSpacer />
                            
                            <Input
                                maxLength="6"
                                type="Number"
                                description="ms"
                                width="10rem"
                                fieldWidth="50%">
                            </Input>
                            
                            <Input
                                maxLength="6"
                                type="Number"
                                description="ms"
                                width="10rem"
                                fieldWidth="50%">
                            </Input>
                            
                        </Toolbar>                        
                    </headerToolbar>                    
                </Table>
 
            </mvc:View>
        </script>
 
        <script>
            sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
                "use strict";
 
                //### THE APP: place the XMLView somewhere into DOM ###
                sap.ui.xmlview({
                    viewContent : jQuery("#myXmlView").html()
                }).placeAt("content");
 
            });
        </script>
 
    </head>
 
    <body class="sapUiBody">
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, it looks like you actually need **width** property to define control size. **fieldWidth** just defines input box width, not entire control (including description etc).